# unclosed gsp expression, null pointer, even though it is not

Tags: grails, gsp

I am using the following code to make a loop and use if for creating tabs.

```
<g:set var="task_list" value="${Task.findAllByEmployee_idAndProject_id(session.user.id,session.id_of_project)}"/>

            <g:set var="task_number" value="${task_list.size()}"/>

            <g:if test="${task_number}">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#demo1" aria-expanded="true">${task_list[0].task_name}</a></li>

                  <g:each var ="i" in="${2.. task_number }" >

                  <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#demo${i }" aria-expanded="false">${task_list[i]?.task_name}

                  </a></li>
                  </g:each>

                </ul>
            </g:if>
```

however. it shows Cannot get property 'task_name' on null object
 I have already check that it is not a null object by writing it as

```
${task_list[1].task_name}
```

I have already tried using

```
`${task_list[${i}].task_name}`
```

it shows

> Unclosed GSP expression.

Comment: `${2.. task_number}` shouldn't have a space. It should be `${2..task_number}` ... that might be an issue.

Comment: I have already tried that . it's not it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm sure you know you skip the task # 1. Other than that, I'd default to a save range retrieval like this:

```
(2..task_number).toList()
```

That's syntacticly an overkill but will do the job.

It would also make sense to print out the current value of `i` (e.g. `${i}` somewhere after the `g:each`)

Finally I don't think it is a good idea to load data needed by a view in that view. That's what controllers and services are for. If you really need to load data in a view wrap it in a custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify your code to:

```
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

            <g:each var="task" in="${task_list}" status="i">

              <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#demo${i}" aria-expanded="${0 == i}">${task.task_name}

              </a></li>
            </g:each>

          </ul>
```

Thus, the default iteration capability is used, and the 0th task gets expanded by default